# How do I get an access_token for a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've created a dummy page and I'm trying to browse
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=MY_AUTH_TOKEN
but all I get is an empty answer.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here on facebook and authentication : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: @lribinik you still need a token - you can apply for one from the documentation page - read it ..